# Simple Git Merge (Use Cherry Pick or Merge option?)

Tags: git, version-control, github, merge, git-merge

I have the following branches in my Git repository:

- master
- release-1.0
- bugfix-abc

I have merged the *bugfix-abc* branch into *master* but should have merged it into the *release-1.0* branch. This is fine since *master* will eventually need these changes anyway. *Master* has also received several other commits which should not be in the release branch.

What is the preferred method of merging just the commits that were formerly made in *bugfix-abc* into *release-1.0*? Note that the *bugfix-abc* branch has been deleted. I do have a list of the individual commit IDs if that helps since there were only 3.

I've been reading about the difference between merging and cherry picking but still not quite sure which best applies best in this situation. Since the *release-1.0* branch will eventually be merged back into *master* I want to be sure I cause as little conflict as possible at that time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the commit IDs, you can recreate the branch using ID of the last commit:

```
git branch bugfix-abc 123abc
```

Then, you can merge it into master normally:

```
git checkout master
git merge bugfix-abc
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had actually thought about this and wondered if it would work. Quick question, if I have a merge commit (Merge remote-tracking branch 'asdf123') should I create the branch from that, or the commit immediately before it? I assume the latter.

Comment: No problem :-) Your assumption is correct - create the branch from the commit immediately before the merge.

Comment: That seems to have worked just fine. Thanks again! I'm really curious to see how this works out when merging the release branch back into master. Hopefully not a big conflict mess. Either way, the code is exactly where it needs to be right now so that's just fine with me. :)